How to simulate user interaction with Python Telegram app WebApp for unit tests?
I'm trying to write unit tests for a telegram bot. I have the following test:
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_add_revent():
        await CLI.send_msg("/new")
        resp = await CLI.fetch_responses(1)
        assert resp[0].message == "Launching portal..."
        # Send mock request

The bot uses a WebApp launched from the telegram inline keyboard for the user to add an event to their calendar. I want to simulate this somehow.
I've looked at the Telegram docs and found this method, but I don't understand how I can create a request simulating this myself. I've looked at a similar question here , but haven't found an answer for more complex requests than simply sending a message.
